# Uploaded images don't save in destination folder

Tags: php, file-upload, saving-data

I am new here, nice to meet you.

I'm trying create a clean copy of a picture uploaded by a user after security checks, and to save this copy in a designated folder and in my DB. I'm working with XAMPP on Windows 10 and I granted the right permissions for the said folder. My code is below:

```
/*bit of code for picture addition, in a function for album publication*/
if($_FILES['albumCover']['error'] === 0) {
    $covType;
    $createCover;
    $covName = guidv4();

    $imgRegex = '/^[a-z\d][^.]*\.(jpe?g$)|\.(png$)/i';

    $covInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $covMime = finfo_file($covInfo, $_FILES['albumCover']['tmp_name']);
    finfo_close($covInfo);

    if(!preg_match($imgRegex, $_FILES['albumCover']['name']) ||
       str_contains($_FILES['albumCover']['name'], ' ') ||
       in_array($_FILES['albumCover']['type'], ['image/jpeg','image/png'])||
       strpos($covMime, 'image/') !== 0) 
    {

        $addMessages['errors'][] = 'Caractère autorisé pour le nom d\'image : lettres sans 
              accent / sans trémas / sans cédille, chiffres, tirets et underscores. Fichiers
              autorisés : images .jpg, .jpeg ou .png.';
    }

    if(empty($addMessages['errors'])) {

        if(preg_match($imgRegex, $_FILES['albumCover']['name'])
             && $_FILES['albumCover']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'
             && strpos($covMime, 'image/') !== 0) 
        {

            $covType = 'jpeg';
            $createCover = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['albumCover']['tmp_name']);

            imagejpeg($createCover,
                self::COV_SECURE_PATH.$covName.'.'.pathinfo($_FILES['albumCover']['name'], 
                      PATHINFO_EXTENSION)
            );

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['albumCover']['tmp_name'],
            self::COV_SECURE_PATH.'/'.$_FILES['albumCover']['name']);
        } elseif(preg_match($imgRegex, $_FILES['albumCover']['name'])
                && $_FILES['albumCover']['type'] == 'image/png'
                && strpos($covMime, 'image/') !== 0) 
        {

            $covType = 'png';
            $createCover = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['albumCover']['tmp_name']);

            imagepng($createCover,
                    self::COV_SECURE_PATH.$covName.'.'.pathinfo($_FILES['albumCover']['name'],
                   PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['albumCover']['tmp_name'],
            self::COV_SECURE_PATH.'/'.$_FILES['albumCover']['name']);
        }
    }
}
```

A few more details: the bit of code above is part of a class method. The constant COV_SECURE_PATH is declared in the class, before the method. And the guidv4() function for the picture name is in the same file, before the declaration of the class.

I have no PHP error messages, my prints display the right name and extension of each file and I declared the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" in my HTML form. The pictures are saved in my DB (I will add the code regarding the DB if needed), but they won't be saved in my folder and I don't know what I'm missing. So far I haven't found an answer when searching in any site, any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: _I granted the right permissions for the said folder_ On windows you dont normally have to do anything. Can you show what you did to do this

Comment: How about adding an `else` to the `if - elseif` so you get an error or some sort of notification when the code does not go into either the if or the elseif

Comment: As `imagepng() / imagejpeg()` creates a file and `move_uploaded_file()` copies the file, did you really want 2 of each file?

Comment: You have path `self::COV_SECURE_PATH.$covName` in `imagejpeg` and `self::COV_SECURE_PATH.'/'` in `move_uploaded_file`. Does the function `guidv4()`  add slash to `$covName`?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers.

I wasn't sure the move_uploaded_file() was necessary, but I wanted to try since the imagepng() / imagejpeg() don't work. So I'll remove the move_uploaded_file().

I simply did a chmod 777 for the permissions in the folder and the parent folders.

And the guidv4() function does not add a slash to $covName.

Comment: And I added an else to display a custom message, when the code doesn't go into the if or elseif. The code enters only into the else every time I try to upload an image, so I always get my custom message saying that the file couldn't be saved in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have finally fixed everything. My error was: `if(preg_match($imgRegex, $_FILES['albumCover']['name']) && $_FILES['albumCover']['type'] == 'image/jpeg' && strpos($covMime, 'image/') !== 0) {`

instead of `if(preg_match($imgRegex, $_FILES['albumCover']['name']) && $_FILES['albumCover']['type'] == 'image/jpeg' && strpos($covMime, 'image/') === 0) {`

And I also realised that I hadn't activated GD in my php.ini, now it's done.
Thanks to everyone who answered me!

Answer (score -1):

take a look at my image validation...

```
//connecting to the database
$mysqli = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'img_validation' )
or
die( 'Database connection error => '.mysqli_connect_error() );

//errors and success message handling
$errors = array();
$success = array();

//imgs dir
$imgs_dir = './assets/imgs/';

//if upload button is pressed...
if ( isset( $_POST['upload'] ) ) {

    //get image info...
    $imgName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $imgTmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $imgSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];

    //image validation
    if ( $imgName ) {
        //get extension info
        $imgExt = strtolower( pathinfo( $imgName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
        //allowed image extensions
        $allowExt  = array( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png' );
        //create new random image name
        $uploadedPic = 'user-upload-'.rand( 100000, 999999 ).'.'.$imgExt;

        //validate image extension
        if ( in_array( $imgExt, $allowExt ) ) {
            //max image upload size 3MB
            if ( $imgSize < 3000000 ) {
                //move image file to designated directory/folder
                move_uploaded_file( $imgTmp, $imgs_dir.$uploadedPic );
            } else {
                array_push( $errors, "Image too large. Max. upload size 3MB." );
            }
        } else {
            array_push( $errors, "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('JPG, JPEG and PNG formats required.\\nMax. upload size 3MB.');</script>" );
            array_push( $errors, "Please select a valid image." );
        }
    } else {
        $uploadedPic;
    }

    //if found no errors...
    if ( count( $errors ) == 0 ) {
        //insert new record in `user_uploads` table in the database...
        $admin = mysqli_query( $mysqli, "INSERT INTO user_uploads (image) VALUES ('$uploadedPic');" );
        if ( $admin == 1 ) {
            //success message
            array_push( $success, "Image uploaded successfully." );
            //redirect to profile after 2 seconds...
            header( 'refresh: 2; url=http://localhost/img-validation/' );
        } else {
            array_push( $errors, mysqli_error() );
        }
    }
}
```

When I was at the early learning stage of PHP, I write this code and hope this will work for you : )

Comment: Hello Tabassam, thank you. Yes, I used a similar code during my recent training course in junior web development. :) Now, I am building my first "real" site, so I'm trying to get things more secure than I did for the site I delivered to pass my exam. Thus I'm trying to use imagecreatefrom(), and this just doesn't seem to work. As for the size, extension and name checks, as well as the saving in my DB, my code works too.

Comment: @WilleB Bro, my script will store only the random image name in the `user_uploads` table in the DB, which is stored in the `$uploadedPic` variable. And the actual image will store on your local machine, I mean in your designated folder. Hope you understand : )

Comment: Yes I know :), it seems I haven't answered clearly, sorry. I'm trying to create a clean copy of an uploaded image, and to save this copy in my designated folder, with the functions imagecreatefrom() and imagepng() / imagejpeg(), instead of using the function move_uploaded_file.

Comment: OK, I found and corrected a stupid error of mine. Now I get this PHP error: "Call to undefined function App\controller\imagecreatefromjpeg()". I'll search how to fix it.

Comment: Debugging is such a headache that becomes more interesting when you debug your own code ; ) Well, congrats on being it done, and wish you good luck for your exam.

Comment: Thank you! I'm confident on the fact that I'll pass my exam, still it's very nice of you. I wish you a nice day.

Comment: Yout too and Welcome : )